# Accessing presentingViewController while dismissal animation of a Modal View Controller

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiviewcontroller

I have a button within the main view controller, that presents modally another view controller. I made a custom animation of main view controller being dimmed while modal vc slides up. But how can I make it go backwards while modal vc slides down (using dismiss)?
Using the tutorial on [this site](https://sectionfive.net/blog/2015/10/23/a-swift-solution-to-view-dismissal/) , I created protocols to access the presenting vc, but animation does not happen, it just instantly changes the opacity.

Also, if I put the animation code into the viewWillAppear of the presenting vc, it starts the animation only when the modal vc slides down all the way (disappears). I did not use regular show segue because I don't think that's the best way to get rid of a modal vc. If I am wrong, please correct me

This is the prepareForSegue in the presenting vc

```
 override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if let identifier = segue.identifier{
        switch identifier {
        case "showSettings":
            let tempFrame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.bounds.width, height: self.view.bounds.height)
            dimView = UIView(frame: tempFrame)
            dimView.backgroundColor = .black
            dimView.layer.opacity = 0
            self.view.addSubview(dimView)
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
                self.dimView.layer.opacity = 0.4
            })
        default:break
        }
    }
    if let vc = segue.destination as? Dismissable
    {
        vc.dismissalDelegate = self
    }
}
```

Here is an IBaction, that dismisses the modal vc within itself.

```
    @IBAction func dismiss() {
    dismissalDelegate?.finishedShowing(viewController: self)
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, animations:{
        (self.dismissalDelegate as! ViewController).dimView.layer.opacity = 0.3
    })
}
```

Comment: Maybe you should do this by way of unwindsegue. Google it, and you will find several tutorials for this.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I managed to go back to the presenting VC using unwindSegue (new technique for me, pretty convenient, thanks for that :D), but animation still did not happen, it constantly changed the opacity of a presenting vc view before it appeared.

Comment: The trick is to generate a screenshot of the presenting VC, and use that as a background for the presented VC. Then you do whatever animations you want with that image. Then when your animation is done it looks like your unwinding is done, so you can just pop the presented VC with no animation.

Comment: Wow, is there a way to generate a screenshot programmatically? I really doubt it, and here comes a problem, how should I optimize it for all devices? The solution I have right now looks not quite as it is supposed to, but close, and I am not sure, that it's worth to use this trick. I access presenting vc through the delegate, change it's opacity with no animation to 0.3 and in its viewWillAppear change it to 0 in 0.5 seconds. It's almost good :D I guess I better focus on more important features of my clumsy app

Comment: Adding an answer with some example code for you. Not sure if it is swift 2 or 3, but it should give you some pointers

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll look into it

Answer (score 0):

This is just an example of how it could be done. Pretty sure it's far from perfect, but should work as a starting point. There is a lot of code there specific to an old project I had, but that can be stripped away.

```
final class ModalSeguePushStyle : UIStoryboardSegue
{
    override func perform() {
        let sourceVC = self.sourceViewController
        let destinationVC = self.destinationViewController
        var endPosition = destinationVC.view.frame
        var startPostition = destinationVC.view.frame

        startPostition.origin.x = startPostition.width

        if sourceVC.navigationController != nil
        {
            startPostition.origin.y = -44
            endPosition.origin.y = -44
        }

        destinationVC.view.frame = startPostition

        sourceVC.view.addSubview(destinationVC.view)

        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3, animations: { () -> Void in
            destinationVC.view.frame = endPosition
            }) { (Bool) -> Void in
                self.sourceViewController.presentViewController(self.destinationViewController, animated: false, completion: nil)
        }
    }
}

final class ModalSeguePushStyleUnwind : UIStoryboardSegue
{
    func createMockView(view: UIView) -> UIImageView {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.frame.size, true, UIScreen.mainScreen().scale)

        view.drawViewHierarchyInRect(view.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)
        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()

        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return UIImageView(image: image)
    }

    override func perform() {
        let sourceVC = self.sourceViewController
        let destinationVC = self.destinationViewController
        var endPosition = sourceVC.view.frame

        endPosition.origin.x += endPosition.width

        var bar:UIImageView?
        let mock = createMockView(destinationVC.view)

        if destinationVC.navigationController != nil
        {
            mock.frame.origin.y = 64
        }

        sourceVC.view.superview!.insertSubview(mock, atIndex: 0)

        if let b = destinationVC.tabBarController?.tabBar
        {
            bar = createMockView(b)
            bar?.frame = b.frame
            sourceVC.view.superview!.insertSubview(bar!, aboveSubview: mock)
        }

        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3, animations: { () -> Void in
            sourceVC.view.frame = endPosition
            }) { (Bool) -> Void in
                sourceVC.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion: { () -> Void in

                })
        }
    }
}
```